# __contains filter doesn't work on mysql, works on local SQLite db

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have following code snippet:

```
profiles_list = Profile.objects.filter(
    company=request.user.company,
)
search_query = None
search_key = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    search_key = request.POST.get('skey')
    search_query = request.POST.get('squery', None)
    profiles_list = profiles_list.filter(
        **{'%s__contains' % search_key:search_query}
    )
```

On my local dev machine with SQLite database, if I type in search_query, for example "Owal"
it returns me a record where search_key contains "Owal", so I get for example "Kowalski".

I tried it on production server with MySQL and it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/):

> SQLite doesn’t support case-sensitive LIKE statements; contains acts
>   like icontains for SQLite. See the database note for more information.

Suggestion: Use `%s__icontains` instead.